# how to get a card position in RecyclerView.Adapter?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Please help me with a problem. The problem is that I need to get the card position to convey this position to another Activity. I need to transfer this position when I pressed the button on the card. How to get the card position?

**RVAdapter.java**

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

    private final static String myLog = "myLog";


    List<ItemsOfRow> items;
    private Context context;


    RVAdapter(List<ItemsOfRow> items, Context context) {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view, viewGroup, false);
        PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {


        personViewHolder.imgGroupImage.setImageBitmap(items.get(i).getTitleImage());
        personViewHolder.txtTitleGroup.setText(items.get(i).getTitleName());
        personViewHolder.txtContentGroup.setText(items.get(i).getTitleContent());


        personViewHolder.btnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, items.get(????).getTitleContent());
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                context.startActivity(sendIntent);
            }
        });

        personViewHolder.btnLearnMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, QuoteActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title",items.get(?????).getTitleName());
                intent.putExtra("positionGroup", ?????? + "");
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        CardView cv;

        TextView txtTitleGroup;
        TextView txtContentGroup;

        ImageView imgGroupImage;

        Button btnShare;
        Button btnLearnMore;


        PersonViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);



            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);

            imgGroupImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_group_image);
            txtTitleGroup = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title_group);
            txtContentGroup = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_content_group);


            btnShare = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_share_group);
            btnLearnMore = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_learn_more);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: inside **onBindViewHolder** method, **i** is your card position.

Comment: @RahulSharma, the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) explicitly states that you should not use that parameter for this purpose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use method `getAdapterPosition()` of your viewHolder

Comment: Thanks, it helped me.

Comment: @VladislavBuryakinBeowulF accept answer if it correct, please

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter `int i` of `onBindViewHolder()` is actually the position of the card that is going to be created. You can just pass `i` to your intent.

In your `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {

    /* rest of your code */

    personViewHolder.btnLearnMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, QuoteActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title",items.get(i).getTitleName());
            intent.putExtra("positionGroup", i);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(child)
```

This will return the position of the view in the recycler view.
Here child is the View that registers the click event.

A full click listener code can be similar to:

```
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
```